# Phantomjs: take screenshot of the current page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to use `Phantomjs` to capture a screenshot from the same page that the user is on.

For example, A user is on *my-page.html* and has made some changes to the elements of this page, now I need to take a screenshot of an element (DIV) inside this page (my-page.html) and save it.

I found a few examples of `Phantomjs and php` which I tested and worked on my server and it stores the image on my server too BUT all of the examples I found are for taking screenshots of external pages/URLs and not the 'current page'.

This is fairly a straight forward process in Html2canvas but the quality of the produced image is not good at all so I decided to use Phantomjs to produce higher quality screenshots AND also it allows me to zoom in on the page.

Here is a simple example of using Phantomjs for taking screenshot of External URL's:

```
var system = require("system");
if (system.args.length > 0) {
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open(system.args[1], function() {
        //viewportSize being the actual size of the headless browser
page.viewportSize = { width: 3000, height: 3000 };
//the clipRect is the portion of the page you are taking a screenshot of
page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 3000, height: 3000 };
page.zoomFactor = 300.0/72.0;

        var pageTitle = system.args[1].replace(/http.*\/\//g, "").replace("www.", "").split("/")[0]
        var filePath = "img/" + pageTitle + '.png';
        page.render(filePath);
        console.log(filePath);
        phantom.exit();
    });
}
```

Could someone please let me know if this is possible at all?

**EDIT (Answer to my own question),**

it turns out that you cannot take a screenshot of the current page if the page's elements have been edited by the user on the live basis. the only screenshots you can take with phantomjs is a bare bone of the page.

Reason: phantomjs is a headless browser and uses QtWebKit which runs on the server and it is not a javascript library same as html2canvas.

Explained and experienced by others [HERE](http://www.chrisle.me/2013/08/5-reasons-i-chose-selenium-over-phantomjs/):

Another use case that is an issue for a project I’m working on is that you need drag and drop. Headless drivers have some basic functionality, but if you need to be able to set precise coordinates you’re stuck with Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

For taking screenshot of current page you must pass the correct URL to Phantom script

Syntax :

```
phantomjs <"Phantom code url(as in documentation report.js)"> <"page url of which you want to take scrrenshot"> <"result saving url">
```

Now assuming you are passing correct URL :

1. In my case **I was unable to take screenshot of my page as there was a spring security annotation to it**, so it was not letting me to proceed so Please check for any security you added to your page if yes then remove it and then try again.
2. If case 1 does not apply to you surely there is an problem with URL you are passing please double check it.

Please let me know if problem still persist please post any errors(if occurring) you are getting.

Comment: I think you didn't quite get the question! I'm not getting any error at all. all i need to know is if its possible to take a screenshot of the current page as opposed to taking screenshots of external URL's which seems to be explained on all the phantomjs examples!!

Comment: Yes you can take screenshot of current page.

Comment: I followed https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/automate-report-generation-using-phantomjs/ this link with my custom changes.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. phantomjs is a headless browser which runs on the server. how can it detect what page the user is on and what changes have been made to the elements on that page by the user and then take a screenshot of it?!

Comment: nope, It is not possible to take a screenshot of the current page IF expecting to take screenshot of the latest changes made by the user on the elements of the page. i.e. in a drag and drop scenario.